# I have 3 dll's that keep crashing windows 7 explorer (stops and restarts)

Tags: windows-explorer

I have 3 dll's that keep crashing windows 7 explorer (stops and restarts)SHELL32.dll,ADIST64.dll,
BfLLr.dll Indicated in windows logs application Computer Management (log)